# Issue with getting a graphical object to print to panel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, repaint

I am having issues with the below program I have been working on. The program is supposed to take the users' input via a GUI and then use those to create and draw an object. After some testing I know that the object (either oval or rectangular) is being created. The issue I am running into is that the object is not being drawn within the panel. What am I doing wrong here and how can I get the draw method to be called. I am very new to the graphics methods and maybe making a simple mistake.

````
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * Purpose: This GUI will take a users input to print a shape
 */
public class Test {

 //Shape class that extends the base rectangle class   
 public abstract static class Shape extends Rectangle {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   // instance variables for shape class
   private String color;
   private Boolean solid;
   private int count;

   // Constructor for shape class
   public Shape(Rectangle rectangle, String color, Boolean solid) 
{
       super(rectangle);
       this.color = color;
       this.solid = solid;
       count++;

   }

      // Method that will give the number of shapes printed
   public  int  getNoOfShapes() {
       return count;
   }
   // method that will take the users color select and set the color

   public void setColor(Graphics g) {
       if(color.equalsIgnoreCase("black"))
           g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
       else if(color.equalsIgnoreCase("red"))
           g.setColor(Color.RED);
       else if(color.equalsIgnoreCase("orange"))
           g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
       else if(color.equalsIgnoreCase("yellow"))
           g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
       else if(color.equalsIgnoreCase("green"))
           g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
       else if(color.equalsIgnoreCase("blue"))
           g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
       else if(color.equalsIgnoreCase("magenta"))
           g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
   }
   // return shape type is solid or hollow
   public Boolean getSolid() {
       return solid;
   }

   // draw method
   public abstract void draw(Graphics g);
}

 //Oval subclass
  public static class Oval extends Shape {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   // Constructor for the oval class
   public Oval(Rectangle rectangle, String color, Boolean solid) {
       super(rectangle, color, solid);

   }

   //Draw method for the oval 
   @Override
   public void draw(Graphics g) {
       // Draw a hollow oval shape
       if(super.getSolid() == false)
           g.drawOval((int)getX(), (int)getY(), (int)getWidth(), (int)getHeight());
       //Draw a solid oaval shape
       else if(super.getSolid() == true)
           g.fillOval((int)getX(),(int) getY(), (int)getWidth(), (int)getHeight());
   }

}

  //Rectangular subclass
  public static class Rectangular extends Shape {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   // Constructor for Rectangular class
   public Rectangular(Rectangle rectangle, String color, Boolean solid) {
       super(rectangle, color, solid);
   }

   //Method to draw a rectangle
   @Override
   public void draw(Graphics g) {
       // Will draw a hollow rectangle
       if(super.getSolid() == false)
           g.drawRect((int)getX(), (int)getY(), (int)getWidth(), (int)getHeight());
       //Will draw a solid rectangle
       else if(super.getSolid() == true)
           g.fillRect((int)getX(), (int)getY(), (int)getWidth(), (int)getHeight());
   }

}



//Drawing class with GUI inside
public static class Drawing extends JPanel {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   // create Shape 
   private Shape shape1=null;

   public void drawShape(Shape shape) throws OutsideBounds{
   try { 
           if(shape.intersects(270,20,200,200))
               throw new OutsideBounds("This shape will not fit into the drawing box");
       }catch(OutsideBounds o) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, o.getMessage());
       }catch(Exception e) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please only enter integers ");
       }
   }

   // Method to paint shape
   @Override
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

       try {
           // print count of shapes
           super.paintComponents(g);
           shape1.setColor(g);
           shape1.draw(g);
           repaint();

       }catch(Exception e) {}
   }

}

public static class GUI{
   // Instance variables for the GUI
  // private JFrame window;
   private JLabel shape;
   private JLabel fillType;
   private JLabel color;
   private JLabel width;
   private JLabel height;
   private JLabel xCoordinate;
   private JLabel yCoordinate;
   private JLabel printCount;
   private JComboBox<String> cshape;
   private JComboBox<String> cfillType;
   private JComboBox<String> ccolor;
   private JTextField widthField;
   private JTextField heightField;
   private JTextField  xField;
   private JTextField yField;
   private JButton draw;
   private JButton clear;
   private JButton exit;
   private JPanel panel;



   // Constructor that will initiate GUI variables
   public  GUI() {
       JFrame window = new JFrame();
       window.setSize(500,350); // set size fo frame
       window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       window.setLayout(null); // set no layout
       window.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // centered frame
       window.setTitle("Geometric Drawing"); // title
       shape=new JLabel("Shape Type");
       fillType=new JLabel("Fill Type");
       color=new JLabel("Color");
       width=new JLabel("Width");
       height=new JLabel("Height");
       xCoordinate=new JLabel("x coordinate");
       yCoordinate=new JLabel("y coordinate");
       printCount=new JLabel("1");
       cshape=new JComboBox<>(new String[] {"Oval","Rectangle"});
       cfillType=new JComboBox<>(new String[] {"Solid","Hollow"});
       ccolor=new JComboBox<>(new String[] {"Black","Red","Orange","Yellow","Green","Blue","Magenta"});
       widthField=new JTextField();
       heightField=new JTextField();
       xField=new JTextField();
       yField=new JTextField();
       draw=new JButton("Draw");
       clear = new JButton("clear");
       exit = new JButton("exit");
       panel=new JPanel();
       // set border with title to panel
       panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Shape Drawing"));

       // adding all parts to the window 
       window.add(shape);
       window.add(fillType);
       window.add(color);
       window.add(width);
       window.add(height);
       window.add(xCoordinate);
       window.add(yCoordinate);
       window.add(printCount);
       window.add(cshape);
       window.add(cfillType);
       window.add(ccolor);
       window.add(widthField);
       window.add(heightField);
       window.add( xField);
       window.add(yField);
       window.add(draw);
       window.add(clear);
       window.add(exit);
       window.add(panel);

       // set positions within the window
       shape.setBounds(20, 20, 100, 30);
       fillType.setBounds(20, 55, 100, 30);
       color.setBounds(20, 90, 100, 30);
       width.setBounds(20, 125, 100, 30);
       height.setBounds(20, 160, 100, 30);
       xCoordinate.setBounds(20, 195, 100, 30);
       yCoordinate.setBounds(20, 230, 100, 30);
       printCount.setBounds(285, 40, 20, 30);
       cshape.setBounds(140, 20, 100, 30);
       cfillType.setBounds(140, 55, 100, 30);
       ccolor.setBounds(140, 90, 100, 30);
       widthField.setBounds(140, 125, 100, 30);
       heightField.setBounds(140, 160, 100, 30);
        xField.setBounds(140, 195, 100, 30);
       yField.setBounds(140, 230, 100, 30);
       draw.setBounds(230, 280, 80, 30);
       clear.setBounds(120, 280,80,30);
       exit.setBounds(330, 280,80,30);
       panel.setBounds(270, 20, 200, 200);
       // adding action listener to draw button
      // draw.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
       window.setVisible(true); // make frame visible

       draw.addActionListener(
    new java.awt.event.ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
               try {

           Drawing d1 = new Drawing();       
           Shape shape;
           String color;
           int xCoord = 0, yCoord = 0, width = 0, height = 0; 

           //Point accounting for the needed shift

           xCoord = Integer.parseInt(xField.getText() + 270);
           yCoord = Integer.parseInt(yField.getText() + 50);
           width = Integer.parseInt(widthField.getText());
           height = Integer.parseInt(heightField.getText());

           Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle (xCoord, yCoord, width, height);

          // Point p = new Point(shapeX+270, shapeY+50);
           //setting dimensions based off user input 
           //Dimension d = new Dimension(shapeWidth, shapeHeight);
           if(((String) cshape.getSelectedItem()).equalsIgnoreCase("oval")){
               shape = new Oval(r1, (String)ccolor.getSelectedItem(), true);
               System.out.print("creating oval");
                 }
               else{
               shape = new Rectangular(r1,(String)ccolor.getSelectedItem(), true);}
            d1.drawShape(shape);

           window.repaint(); // call paint() method

       }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please only enter integers ");
       }    catch (OutsideBounds ex) {    
                Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }    

    }
    });

    //Action Listener for clear button
       clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            //Clearing all text fields   
            widthField.setText("");
            heightField.setText("");
            xField.setText("");
            yField.setText("");
                                }
       });

        //Action Liistener for exit button
       exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            //message to the user   
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Program is ending");
            window.dispose();}
       });        
   }
}


 // Out of bounds class
public static class OutsideBounds extends Exception {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   // parameterized constructor
   public OutsideBounds(String errorMessage) {
       // call super class parameterized constructor
       super(errorMessage);   
   }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
       GUI G1 = new GUI();  // Creating GUI

   }

}```
````

Comment: I started out reading the code thinking, "this is a good start, some nice ideas", but the further I read into, the more it began to come apart until it ended in a complete train wreak - sorry, but it just did.  The primary issue you're having is the fact that `Drawing` is never added to anything which could possibly paint it, but, you should only ever have a single drawing instance, instead of trying to create multiple instances in the `ActionListener`

Answer (score 1):

There are a number small problems, which are combining to produce a larger problem.

1. `null` layouts are just a bad idea.  Take the time to learn how to use and mix appropriate layouts
2. Don't use `String` as a carrier of information if you can avoid it.  It's too easy to screw up.  In you case, learn how to make use of a `ListCellRenderer` to customise the `JComoboBox` so it can carry `Color` as it's base value
3. There should be a single instance of `Drawing` which should render ALL the shapes.  You then add each new shape to it.  Instead of trying to create new instances for each individual shape.
4. In order for something to be painted, it must be added to something which can be painted.  This means that the `Drawing` panel needs to be added to your frame at some point (or a contained which is directly or indirectly contained within your frame).

This is a very basic re-work of your code.  It will generate a oval or rectangle at a random location with a random color.  I'll leave you to fill in the rest of your requirements around it

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

public class Test {

    //Shape class that extends the base rectangle class   
    public abstract static class Shape extends Rectangle {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        // instance variables for shape class
        private String color;
        private Boolean solid;
        private int count;

        // Constructor for shape class
        public Shape(Rectangle rectangle, String color, Boolean solid) {
            super(rectangle);
            this.color = color;
            this.solid = solid;
            count++;

        }

        // Method that will give the number of shapes printed
        public int getNoOfShapes() {
            return count;
        }
        // method that will take the users color select and set the color

        public void setColor(Graphics g) {
            if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("black")) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            } else if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("red")) {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
            } else if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("orange")) {
                g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            } else if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("yellow")) {
                g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            } else if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("green")) {
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("blue")) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            } else if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("magenta")) {
                g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            }
        }
        // return shape type is solid or hollow

        public Boolean getSolid() {
            return solid;
        }

        // draw method
        public abstract void draw(Graphics g);
    }

    //Oval subclass
    public static class Oval extends Shape {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        // Constructor for the oval class
        public Oval(Rectangle rectangle, String color, Boolean solid) {
            super(rectangle, color, solid);

        }

        //Draw method for the oval 
        @Override
        public void draw(Graphics g) {
            // Draw a hollow oval shape
            if (super.getSolid() == false) {
                g.drawOval((int) getX(), (int) getY(), (int) getWidth(), (int) getHeight());
            } //Draw a solid oaval shape
            else if (super.getSolid() == true) {
                g.fillOval((int) getX(), (int) getY(), (int) getWidth(), (int) getHeight());
            }
        }

    }

    //Rectangular subclass
    public static class Rectangular extends Shape {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        // Constructor for Rectangular class
        public Rectangular(Rectangle rectangle, String color, Boolean solid) {
            super(rectangle, color, solid);
        }

        //Method to draw a rectangle
        @Override
        public void draw(Graphics g) {
            // Will draw a hollow rectangle
            if (super.getSolid() == false) {
                g.drawRect((int) getX(), (int) getY(), (int) getWidth(), (int) getHeight());
            } //Will draw a solid rectangle
            else if (super.getSolid() == true) {
                g.fillRect((int) getX(), (int) getY(), (int) getWidth(), (int) getHeight());
            }
        }

    }

//Drawing class with GUI inside
    public static class Drawing extends JPanel {

        private List<Shape> shapes;
        private List<String> colors; 

        private final Random rnd = new Random();

        public Drawing() {
            shapes = new ArrayList<>(25);
            colors = new ArrayList<>();
            colors.add("black");
            colors.add("red");
            colors.add("orange");
            colors.add("yellow");
            colors.add("green");
            colors.add("blue");
            colors.add("magenta");
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected Rectangle randomBounds() {
            int minSize = 10;
            int avaliableWidth = getWidth() - minSize;
            int avaliableHeight = getHeight() - minSize;

            int width = Math.max(minSize, rnd.nextInt(avaliableWidth / 4));
            int height = Math.max(minSize, rnd.nextInt(avaliableHeight / 4));
            int x = rnd.nextInt(avaliableWidth - width);
            int y = rnd.nextInt(avaliableHeight - height);

            Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
            return bounds;
        }

        protected String randomColor() {
            Collections.shuffle(colors);
            String color = colors.get(0);
            return color;
        }

        public void addCircle() {
            shapes.add(new Oval(randomBounds(), randomColor(), rnd.nextBoolean()));
            repaint();
        }

        public void addRectangle() {
            shapes.add(new Rectangular(randomBounds(), randomColor(), rnd.nextBoolean()));
            repaint();
        }

        // Method to paint shape
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            // print count of shapes
            super.paintComponents(g);
            for (Shape shape : shapes) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                shape.setColor(g2d);
                shape.draw(g2d);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

    }

    public static class GUI {

        private Drawing drawing;

        // Constructor that will initiate GUI variables
        public GUI() {
            JFrame window = new JFrame();
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            window.setTitle("Geometric Drawing"); // title

            JPanel controls = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            controls.add(makeButton("Circle"));
            controls.add(makeButton("Rectangle"));

            drawing = new Drawing();

            window.add(controls, BorderLayout.WEST);
            window.add(drawing);

            window.pack();
            window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            window.setVisible(true); // make frame visible
        }

        protected JButton makeButton(String name) {
           JButton btn = new JButton(name);
           btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   if ("Circle".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
                      drawing.addCircle(); 
                   } else if ("Rectangle".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
                      drawing.addRectangle(); 
                   }
               }
           });
           return btn;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    GUI G1 = new GUI();  // Creating GUI
                }
            });

        }
    }

}
```

Take a look at:

- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

for more details